# Excel: How to countif, with 2 Criteria's?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to only counter the number of cells that have any text written in **Criteria 2** and the date 31-07-2020 in **Criteria 1**.
Can you can help, on how to do it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4vt2.png

Comment: So you don't want Countif but Countifs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`=COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$16,"31-07-2020",$C$3:$C$16,"<>")`

Comment: A little bit of explanation would make this answer much better! Please, consider explaining this solution!

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful. So stupid of me, missing some " ".